# Building public facing web site using SharePoint Onpremises 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, public-website

We have a SharePoint On-premises 2019 and we want to build a public facing web site for the company. So users can  access the web site without having to authenticate?

Is this possible? If this is possible then can anyone provide useful links about creating public facing website using SharePoint on-premises 2019?

Comment: As per [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/v68ikh/sharepoint_and_public_facing_websites/), it is possible to create public facing websites in SP 2019.

Comment: Possible, but generally not a good idea. There are far cheaper and better options.

Comment: @theChrisKent the customer is already planning to get SharePoint server 2019 to build their internal environment, and part of it will be to build public facing web site

Comment: I'm a consultant myself so I understand it isn't always our choice. However, there are many concerns with opening your servers to the public. At the very least, I recommend keeping internal usage as a separate farm that publishes to the public farm. Alternatively, treating SharePoint as a Content repository and pulling data using APIs and exposing that through a site hosted on something else isn't an uncommon strategy either. Bottom line, SharePoint is a bad choice for public sites (security, performance, customization, cost, SEO, etc.), but it's technically possible.

Comment: Agreed with Chris. One thing to note is you need a relatively recent patch level (within 2022, I believe) to use Modern Communication sites with anonymous users. If you're using a Classic Publishing site, you can go with older patches, however you need to be keeping up with patches to be in a supported state with Microsoft.

Comment: @theChrisKent i know that SharePoint is not the 100% suitable tool to build external web sites.. but the customer wants this and they know that SP is not the best tool for this type of web sites.. we are planning to build a separate web application to manage the public facing web site, but we can not afford separate farm,, so security should be handled and for the cost they are already planning to get SP 2019 to manage internal documents and flows..

Comment: @TrevorSeward yes we still did not install the 2019 farm, so once installed we will install all the latest patches till august 2022.. so should we be fine?

Comment: @JohnJohn yes with respect to Modern Communication sites and anonymous access, August 2022 should be good.